# Convert Date formats, keeping time zone

Tags: php, date

I am given a date string formatted like:
May 11, 2017 4:27:00 AM PDT

which I need to convert with **no hour shifting** to 
2017-05-11 16:27:00 .

I am working with

```
$myTime='May 11, 2017 4:27:00 AM PDT';
$formatted= date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($myTime));
```

This returns a time set 7 hours later due to the Unix time conversion.  I can manually subtract 7 or 8 hours (depending on season PST or PDT) to get the result I need, but there must be a better way.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php

Comment: https://eval.in/919256